# Build failed. Could not find type 'System.Globalization.SortVersion'

Tags: mono, xamarin

Somewhere along the line in the last week, Xamarin on my Windows machine started giving the above mentioned error any time I compile with MONO.

Specifically occurs when Project|Active Runtime is MONO - never happens when runtime is Microsoft.NET.

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling MONO runtime (mono-3.2.3-gtksharp-2.12.11-win32-0.exe)

Any clues?  Google searches come up with pretty much nothing

Comment: The problem still exists in 4.2.5 Build 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the same error today, (after an update yesterday to 4.2.4 Build 35) There is a bugfix [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=18770)

Build works fine on another PC without the latest update (4.2.3 build 59). I guess the answer is to roll back to 4.2.3.

You can get it from your account page at Xamarin.com >> Downloads >> View all versions.

Comment: I'm still getting this at version 5.01

Comment: This is still an issue with latest studio.

Answer (score 3):

The solution from [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16467/build-failed-could-not-find-type-system-globalization-sortversion) says that you should either uncheck the box "Use MsBuild" in project settings or use .NET for building but then run with Mono if you want to test runtime compatibility.